# Изменение размера WPF формы при компиляции

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, grid

Вопрос наверно элементарный. Создаю проект, кидаю две кнопки на форму как показано на рисунке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
красной стрелкой указываю на отступ между краем и кнопкой. При компиляции этот отступ имеет меньший размер: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы отступ был таким же как в макете среды? Чтобы не приходилось для каждого добавляемого в грид контрола менять настройки позиционирования

Настройки выравнивания и привязка к краям не меняю, стоят дефолтные.

Comment: Наверно написать правильно РУКАМИ значения и не использовать конструктор для составления интерфейса.

Comment: А на кой тогда конструктор?

Comment: Для того, чтобы видеть, но не разрабатывать. Ваша кнопка например имеет значения по типу `Margin="524, 456, 546, 157"`, не смущает, что они такие большие? А кто их туда впихнул? Правильно, конструктор, ибо он умеет позиционировать объекты банальными отступами и нечего не знает про сетки, про позиционирования и так далее. Научитесь писать XAML сами, не полагаясь на дизайнер, либо чистите и подправляйте за ним косяки (их очень много у него). Ваша кнопка с правильным позиционированием должна выглядеть так `<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="15" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто научитесь пользоваться возможностями XAML разметки.

Когда я впервые узнал о существовании `StackPanel` и `WrapPanel`, моя реакция была что-то типа "а что, так можно было???". Ну и `Grid` - это сетка, вы сами задаете количество колонок и столбцов, их ширину и высоту.

XAML - это просто, но надо изучать доступные контролы, просто так в лоб на марджинах ничего хорошего не получится.

Вот вам короткий пример, показывающий как не умереть от высчитывания `Margin` на калькуляторе.

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!-- занимает столько места, сколько надо содержимому -->
        <RowDefinition/> <!-- занимает всё доступное место, можно указать Height="*" и получить то же самое -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Margin="10" Padding="10,5" Content="Button1"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Padding="10,5" Content="Button2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="Пример текста" Background="Azure"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Margin="10" Padding="10,5" Content="Button3"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Padding="10,5" Content="Button4"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

К тому же, размер окна можно менять, кнопки останутся на ожидаемых местах.

[image: xaml example]

Померял в фотошопе, отступы ровно 10 пикселей, как задано разметкой.

Comment: Отличный совет + примерчик! Спааасибо!!