# Не создаётся окно UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Создаю объект UserControl в главном классе через new UserControl1()
Приходит сообщение из PluginContext.Operations.AddNotificationMessage("UserControl", "UserControl");

а окошка нету... почему так?

cs:

```
namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            PluginContext.Operations.AddNotificationMessage("UserControl", "UserControl");//"дебаг"
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Width="600" Height="320" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FF3C3F3E" AutomationProperties.Name="grid">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="ПАРАМЕТРЫ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К СЕРВЕРУ" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,20"/>
            <Grid Height="185">
                <Label Content="Адрес сервера:" Background="#FF202020" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="30,0,0,140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420" Height="45" TextAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="#FF202020" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Label Content="Логин:" Background="#FF202020" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="30,70,0,70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Admin" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="135" Height="45" BorderBrush="#FF202020" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Label Content="Пароль:" Background="#FF202020" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="315,70,0,70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120"/>
                <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="435,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="135" Height="45" BorderBrush="#FF202020" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Отмена" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="445,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF202020" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Width="155" Height="65" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Сохранить и закрыть" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF202020" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Width="260" Height="65" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Подключение" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF202020" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Width="185" Height="65" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Может ему нужно дать какую нибудь команду как windows form window.ShowDialog();

Но такой не нашла для wpf

Comment: Что такое `PluginContext`? И да `UserControl` - это чисто дизайн, хотите окно, делайте `Window`, в котором уже будет хоть UserControl, хоть что еще. Ну и да, в WPF не принято создавать создавать или как-либо взаимодействовать с элементами UI в C# коде, для этого есть привязки и другие механизмы. Ну и последнее, `Margin="435,0,0,0"` - не пишите потом "почему у меня интерфейс отображается не так, как в дизайнере" или "куда уехала кнопка?", научитесь грамотно распологать объект, без отступов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ PluginContext это библиоткека iiko=(
Сделала в window
Вызываю окно через 
UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();
userControl.Show();

Появляется пустое окно и закрывается сразу

С элементами учту, поработаю над ними)

Comment: А собственно зачем я использую Show()...

Comment: UserControl - не Window, Window - не UserControl. Берете окно, кладете ему в XAML свой юзерконтрол `<local:UserControl1/>` и готово, создаете окно, вызываете Show, окно само создаст ваш юзерконтрол и положит на себя. Готово.

Comment: Берете окно, кладете ему в XAML свой юзерконтрол и готово - не понятно)
Передала в window вызвала через ShowDialog() и все работает =3

Comment: Непонятно что именно? Что такое окно? XAML? Создать объект? Вызвать метод Show? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137895/373567

Comment: а все разобралась) спасибо =3

Comment: а почему я не могу дать лайк комментарию а только репорт кинуть

Comment: У вас с XAML пока кстати дружба неочень, попробуйте познакомиться со `StackPanel`, а то вас убьют марджины. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127243/373567

Comment: У вас наверное репутации маловато для этого.

Comment: Попробую StackPanel спасибо за ответы=)

Comment: @Liana научитесь еще Grid разбивать на колонки и строки, для выравнивания элементов самое оно, для объединения ячеек грида можно Grid.Rowspan и Grid.ColSpan использовать прямо на элементе. StackPanel по сути для создания вертикальной или горизонтальной стопки контролов нужен. А правильную ровную сеточку даст как раз Grid. Марджины понадобятся только для отступов от краев клеточки, где живет контрол.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно предложили, нужно использовать window.ShowDialog();.

Для начала в форме диалогового окна нужно прописать обработку кнопкам Сохранить и закрыть и Отмена

```
private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
}
private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!(bool)RBDeleteFromMAket.IsChecked && !(bool)RBDeleteWithSaves.IsChecked)
    {
        LabelWarn.Content = "выберете один из вариантов";
        return;
    }
        DialogResult = true;
}
```

(код обработки взял из своего проекта, логика конечно может отличаться)

DialogResult - является нужным для нас свойством, от значения которого зависит будут ли применяться изменения

Далее от вашей формы создается объект в том месте, где нужно

и в условии проверяем результат диалога вот так:

```
SomeForm form = new SomeForm();
        if (form.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //через этот объект можем обращаться к открытым полям, тут же вытянуть вам необходимые поля из этой формы
            form.DoSome();
        }
        else    
        {   

        }
```

Comment: Не совсем поняла к чему этот ответ)

Comment: Извините, только сейчас увидел что это какой то другой вид окна - usercontrol), я думал это обычный window